# How to install Apache Airflow on Windows server 2016 / 2019 (NOT WORKING)

Tags: airflow, windows-server, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to install Apache Airflow on Windows webserver 2016.
Steps I performed :

1. install pip
2. pip install apache-airflow

apache airflow installed but not when I'm hitting any of the command nothing is working.

airflow webserver -p 8080
airflow scheduler

Please help me understand is it really possible to install apache airflow in "Windows server 2016"

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: make sure you add airflow command to your PATH.

Comment: @AnirudhBagri Hey Anirudh, Thanks for response... I not getting any error. It just that when I'm running this command "airflow webserver -p 8080 airflow scheduler"
instead of running server this command getting open file

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to install airflow on docker because Docker has window server support.